# Polling service: irregular intervals

Tags: android, service, polling

I've, for test purpose, a little android app composed by a simple activity where you can insert an host, a port and a interval in second. The app starts a service that creates a thread with a cycle that reads from an input stream of a socket until it is intentionally stopped.
Here is the code of the service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    prepareFileLogging();

    FILELOG.info("PollingService: onStartCommand");

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pbIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(this, 0, bIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Notification.Builder bBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync)
                    .setContentTitle("PollingTest")
                    .setContentText("Servizio di polling attivo")
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pbIntent);

    this.startForeground(1, bBuilder.build());

    Log.i("PollingService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

    FILELOG.info("PollingService: Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);


    hostName = intent.getExtras().getString(PAR_HOST);
    portNumber = intent.getExtras().getInt(PAR_PORT);
    freqSeconds = intent.getExtras().getInt(PAR_FREQ);


    if(pollingThread == null){

        FILELOG.info("pollingThread not running: starting...");

        pollingThread = new Poll();
        pollingThread.start();


    }



    Toast.makeText(this, "Servizio in Background: ServizioSincronizzazione.onCreate()",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mReceiver = new BroadcastRec();

    getApplication().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

}




@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder bBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error).setContentTitle(
                    "PollingTest")
            .setContentText("Il Servizio di polling è sinterrotto");

    Toast.makeText(this, "Servizio interrotto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    getApplication().unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

    stopPollingService();
    Log.i("PollingService", "onDestroy");

    super.onDestroy();
}



private class Poll extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();

        FILELOG.info("pollingThread: started");

        try {

            Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

            PrintWriter out =
                    new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in =
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));


            int nanos = 250000;

            while (pollingThread == thisThread) {

                Log.i("PollThread", "start of a new call");

                out.println("prova");
                String response = in.readLine();
                FILELOG.info("pollingThread: server response: " +response);

                System.out.println("server: " + response);

                if (response != null && response.equals("null")) {
                    FILELOG.info("pollingThread: server down (reponse 'null'), new socket");

                    echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
                }


                sendBroadcast(new Intent());

                try {
                    Log.i("PollThread", "timeout start...");
                    Thread.sleep(freqSeconds*1000, nanos);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.i("PollThread", e.getMessage());
                    FILELOG.info("pollingThread error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            FILELOG.info("pollingThread error: Don't know about host " + e.getMessage());

            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            stopPollingService();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            FILELOG.info("pollingThread error: Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                    hostName);
            stopPollingService();


        }


    }
}
```

I've keep the app running on a tablet for one day analyzing the drain of battery and the intervals between two request to the server.
The problem I noticed is that for about 10 minutes the 5 seconds interval is respected, then it changes between 5 and 20 seconds! 
The tablet has been waked up a couple of times and unlocked and the service never crashed.
Here it is the sequence of intervals observed by the server:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/di5WKWA.png]

Someone can think a reason of why this happened?

Comment: I'm thinking your service is being destroyed by the system and then restarted at irregular intervals because you are sending the redeliver intent constant from onStartCommand. You say the server doesn't crash, but is onDestroy ever called?

Comment: onDestroy is never called and onStartCommand is called once!

Answer (score 0):

The system is most likely going into a low power state because the device is idle for 10 minutes. In order to reliably wake up you would need to either use an alarm via the `AlarmManager` or hold a partial wake lock.

Comment: But the tablet was waked up two or three times!

Comment: It may be that your device is going to sleep and suspending its network connectivity, then waking up and connecting again (i.e. wifi).  This could make your socket communication "trickle" in, so your `in.readLine()` call is not happening immediately and causing delays.  In this case your 5 second timeout wouldn't happen until you got a complete line.

Comment: Do you know what does the advanced setting: "Wifi optimization"? Maybe it is related.

Comment: From my experience, it tends to be vendor specific what the platform does to its various hardware components, such as wifi, when going into a low power state.  That being said, the "Wifi optimization" feature available in newer version of Android reduces wifi performance when the screen is off by putting the hardware to sleep for longer periods of time.  So yes, this is most likely related to the behavior which you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do another test with this setting off

Comment: Try holding a partial wake lock.  Note that this is going force the device to stay awake and not go into a low power state when idle, which is going to have a negative impact on battery life.  The other option would be to use AlarmManager to set an alarm for you to wake up and process periodically.  Just make sure it's not too often as then you are right back in the same boat.

Comment: Are you suggesting to use an AlarmManager every 5 seconds? And in the case of holding a partial wake lock can you give me more info?

Comment: I'm actually suggesting judicious use of the AlarmManager or wake locks - both will have a negative effect on battery life over the long term as they either wake the device up or keep it awake. In other words, you should think very carefully about why you want to be aware of network traffic and connectivity every 5 seconds on a mobile device.  Releasing an app which drains battery is not going to sit well with your users.  See the PowerManager and wake lock documentation for more information on wake locks.

Comment: In my case the battery life is not a problem and the app is not to be published.